# Coin toss problem. What is the expected number of flips to required to get HTH?

Tags: probability

A coin is tossed until we get the pattern $HTH$.  Assume that $H$ appears with probability $p$.  What is the expected number of flips required?

My professor gave me a hint

> Condition on the number of flips requried to get $HT$

So we know that it takes $\frac{1}{1-p} + \frac{1}{p}$ to get $HT$

So right now this is what I got so far
 $$E(N) = p(1-p (p(3) + (1-p) (3 + E(N))) + [(1-p)^2 (2+ E(N)) + (p^2 + p(1-p))(....$$

Can anyone help me finish this problem?

Comment: I recommend doing it with states, indexing the states by how much of $HTH$ you have.  Thus the states are indexed by $\emptyset, H, HT$ .  Work out the connections between the three expected lengths and solve a system of linear equations.

Comment: The problem was in the part of the textbook when we are doing conditioning , so I don't think my professor would want us to do states.

Comment: Well, if you know how long it takes to get from nothing to $HT$ then just remark that, starting from $HT$ you either finish in one or you start over (each with probability $\frac 12$).

Comment: The transition probabilities from one state to another *are* conditional probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\tau_0$ be the expected number of flips to get $HTH$ given no flips have taken place, $\tau_1$ the expected number of flips to get $HTH$ given one flip has taken place and it was heads, and $\tau_2$ the expected number of flips to get $HTH$ given two flips have taken place and they were $HT$. Then

\begin{align}
\tau_0 &= 1+p\tau_1 + (1-p)\tau_0\\
\tau_1 &= 1+p\tau_1 + (1-p)\tau_2\\
\tau_2 &= 1+p + (1-p)\tau_0
\end{align}

Solving these equations yields

\begin{align}
\tau_0 &= \frac{1+p(1-p)}{p^2(1-p)}\\
\tau_1 &= \frac1{p^2(1-p)}\\
\tau_2 &= \frac{1-p}{p^2}.
\end{align}